# Mat Menu positioning incorrect

Tags: html, css, angular-material, material-design, angular6

I am currently writing an app, and recently decided to change its direction from "ltr" to "rtl". I have made changes to all of my components accordingly but my mat-menu, that used to appear to the left of its trigger (menu is called from the side bar, application right), is now floating to the left and I cannot seem to make it appear next to its trigger again!

I have tried changing the element style directly from style.scss but to no avail.
I have also tried using mouse-event to try to forcefully change its location but it does not seem to work...

my html code:

```html
<div [matMenuTriggerFor]="general" #trigger="matMenuTrigger"></div>
<button (click)="onClick(trigger)"></button>

<mat-menu #general="MatMenu" overlapTrigger="false">
    <app-menu-content></app-menu-content>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: You should some us some code or show some screenshots of problem. It may help to visualise what you have and what you want. Code shows that you really tried to do so.

Comment: I added a snippet :)

Comment: Are you using the CDK bidi module? https://material.angular.io/cdk/bidi/overview